# Different ways to read large data in python

Tags: python, line

I'm dealing with large data, so finding a good way for reading data is really important.
I'm just a little bit confused about different reading methods.

```
1.f=gzip.open(file,'r')
      for line in f:
          process line
     #how can I process nth line? can I?
2.f=gzip.open(file,'r').readlines()
  #f is a list
  f[10000]
  #we can process nth line

3.f=gzip.open(file,'r')
  while True:
       linelist=list(islice(f,4))

4.for line in fileinput.input():
  process line
```

What's the difference between 2 and 3 ? I just find their memory usage is the same. islice() also needs to first load the whole file into memory (but just later take bit by bit).
And I hear the 4th method is the least memory-consuming, it's really processing bit by bit, right?
For 10GB-scale file, which file-reading method would you recommend? Any thought/information is welcomed.
thx

edit: I think one of my problem is I need to pick out specific lines randomly sometimes.
say:

```
f1=open(inputfile1, 'r')
while True:
    line_group1 = list(islice(f1, 3))
    if not line_group1:
        break
    #then process specific lines say, the second line.
    processed 2nd line
    if ( ....):
           LIST1.append(line_group1[0])
           LIST1.append(processed 2nd line)
           LIST1.append(line_group1[2])
```

And then sth. like

```
with open(file,'r') as f,
    for line in f:
       # process line
```

may not work, am I correct?

Comment: so is the requirement to have random line access to a large text file?

Comment: Well, actually not necessarily. Basically still process line by line; or N lines as a group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot -

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object `f` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

Both 2,3 are not advised for large files as they read & load the entire file contents in memory before processing starts. To read large files you need to find ways to not read the entire file in one single go.

> There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it.

Comment: Couldn't +1 a second time after the edit for the ZEN quotation... Morally done though! ;)

Comment: thx, but can you look at my edit? sometimes I need to pick up specific line (say, 10000th line). Then how can I do ?

Comment: simple, then keep a `counter` which is basically the line num. Check if its 10000th line & do your special handling.

Comment: thx....however, when I tried this way, it's still taking lots of memory.I put a new post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454413/for-line-in-file-object-method-to-read-files

Comment: answered it again now that I get a better understanding of what you need, at that place :)

Answer (score 5):

Check out David M. Beazley's talks on parsing large log files with generators (see the pdf for the presentation):

http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get an index as you iterate over something:

```
for idx, line in enumerate(f):
    # process line
```

Simple and memory efficient. You can actually use `islice` too, and iterate over it without converting to a list first:

```
for line in islice(f,start,stop):
    # process line
```

Neither approach will read the entire file into memory, nor create an intermediate list.

As for `fileinput`, it's just a helper class for quickly looping over standard input or a list of files, there is no memory-efficiency benefit to using it.

As Srikar points out, using the `with` statement is preferred way to open/close a file.

Comment: with islice(f,4), if I don't make a list, then how can I pick out the first, second, third and fourth lines? (like I do in the post)

Comment: Just iterate over it normally, `for line in islice(f,4): print line` would print lines 1,2,3,4. If you wanted lines 2 to 5 you could use `islice(2,6)` instead, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you don't know how many lines until you read and count how many \n in it. 
In 1, you can add a enumerate to get the line number.

Answer (score 0):

For reading specific lines in large files, you could use the [linecache library](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/linecache/index.html#module-linecache).