# "for line in file object" method to read files

Tags: python, line

I'm trying to find out the best way to read/process lines for super large file.
Here I just try

```
for line in f:
```

Part of my script is as below:

```
o=gzip.open(file2,'w')
LIST=[]
f=gzip.open(file1,'r'):
for i,line in enumerate(f):
   if i%4!=3:
      LIST.append(line)

   else:
      LIST.append(line)
      b1=[ord(x) for x in line]
      ave1=(sum(b1)-10)/float(len(line)-1)
      if (ave1 < 84):
         del LIST[-4:]
output1=o.writelines(LIST)
```

My `file1` is around 10GB; and when I run the script, the memory usage just keeps increasing to be like 15GB without any output. That means the computer is still trying to read the whole file into memory first, right? This really makes no different than using `readlines()`

However in the post: 
[Different ways to read large data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448651/different-ways-to-read-large-data-in-python)
Srika told me:
`The for line in f` treats the file object f as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

But obviously I still need to worry large files..I'm really confused.
thx

edit:
Every 4 lines is kind of group in my data.
THe purpose is to do some calculations on every 4th line; and based on that calculation, decide if we need to append those 4 lines.So writing lines is my purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different ways to read large data in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448651/different-ways-to-read-large-data-in-python)

Comment: Anytime that `ave1 >= 84`, those 4 elements you just added to the list become permanent, no? So, does this happen often?

Comment: yeah. when ave1>=84, it won't be deleted. I does happen most of time

Comment: yeah now i understand my problem..

Comment: How are you determining the memory usage? Also, what are you really trying to do? What is special about the number 84? What is the mathematical property you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like at the end of this function, you're taking all of the lines you've read into memory, and then immediately writing them to a file. Maybe you can try this process:

1. Read the lines you need into memory (the first 3 lines).
2. On the 4th line, append the line & perform your calculation.
3. If your calculation is what you're looking for, flush the values in your collection to the file.
4. Regardless of what follows, create a new collection instance.

*I haven't tried this out*, but it could maybe look something like this:

```
o=gzip.open(file2,'w')
f=gzip.open(file1,'r'):
LIST=[]

for i,line in enumerate(f):
   if i % 4 != 3:
      LIST.append(line)
   else:
      LIST.append(line)
      b1 = [ord(x) for x in line]
      ave1 = (sum(b1) - 10) / float(len(line) - 1

      # If we've found what we want, save them to the file
      if (ave1 >= 84):
         o.writelines(LIST)

      # Release the values in the list by starting a clean list to work with
      LIST = []
```

EDIT: As a thought though, since your file is so large, this may not be the best technique because of all the lines you would have to write to file, but it may be worth investigating regardless.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the memory keeps inc. even after you use `enumerator` is because you are using `LIST.append(line)`. That basically accumulates all the lines of the file in a list. Obviously its all sitting in-memory. You need to find a way to not accumulate lines like this. Read, process & move on to next.

One more way you could do is read your file in chunks (in fact reading 1 line at a time can qualify in this criteria, 1chunk == 1line), i.e. read a small part of the file process it then read next chunk etc. I still maintain that this is best way to read files in python large or small.

```
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        <do something with line>
```

The `with` statement handles opening and closing the file, including if an exception is raised in the inner block. The `for line in f` treats the file object `f` as an iterable, which automatically uses buffered IO and memory management so you don't have to worry about large files.

Comment: ok srikar, thx! I understand where's my problem! But then what shall I do NOT to accumulate the lines?

Comment: so instead of adding every line to `LIST`, try to process the line & store the result of that processing. Since I see that you are doing some calculations for certain lines, store only that calculation & not the entire line.

Comment: But my purpose is to append those lines.....I decide if or not to append lines based on calculation on every 4th line.

Comment: you need to explain more. But i still feel this can be solved without accumulating all lines. Which will never scale.

Comment: OK, just as shown in my script: For the first, second, third line, I simply append them; then when it comes to the fourth, I first need to do some calculation, and only when it passes the threshold, will I keep not only 4th line, BUT ALSO the first three lines. But obviously the current script cannot do this. Am I still confusing you? :)

Comment: Or in other words, though I append the first three lines, but their existence or not depends on the fourth line.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "even after you use enumerate", if anything enumerate increases memory usage, albeit, slightly.  Enumerate simply populates the iteration counter in this example (i).  Too see for yourself run: for i, element in enumerate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]): print('%s - %s' % (i, element))

Answer (score 0):

Since you add all the lines to the list `LIST` and only sometimes remove some lines from it, `LIST` we become longer and longer. All those lines that you store in `LIST` will take up memory. Don't keep all the lines around in a list if you don't want them to take up memory.

Also your script doesn't seem to produce any output anywhere, so the point of it all isn't  very clear.

Comment: thx...yeah, this is only part of my script.I'll show all of them

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you know what your problem is already from the other comments/answers, but let me simply state it.

You are only reading a single line at a time into memory, but you are storing a significant portion of these in memory by appending to a list.

In order to avoid this you need to store something in the filesystem or a database (on the disk) for later look up if your algorithm is complicated enough.

From what I see it seems you can easily write the output incrementally.  ie.  **You are currently using a list to store valid lines** to write to output **as well as temporary lines** you may delete at some point.  To be efficient with memory you want to write the lines from your temporary list as soon as you know these are valid output.

In summary, use your list to store only temporary data you need to do your calculations based off of, and once you have some valid data ready for output you can simply write it to disk and delete it from your main memory (in python this would mean you should no longer have any references to it.)

Comment: thanks so much for your kind explanation; now I fully understand my problem. JUst look Doug Swain's comment, it's exactly what I need. thx you guys!

Comment: Great news :), looks like Doug has a good handle on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use the `with` statement , you must close the file's handlers:

```
o.close()

f.close()
```